# Can you store a function in a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, function

e.g.:

```
$functions = array(
  'function1' => function($echo) { echo $echo; }
);
```

Is this possible? What's the best alternative?

Comment: **TL;DR - since PHP 5.4:** `$functions = [ 'function1' => function($echo){ echo $echo; } ];`  
......since PHP 5.3 anonymous functions are available, since 5.4 you can write `[]` instead of `array()`

Comment: PHP 7.4+: `$sort = [SORT_ASC => fn($a, $b) => $a <=> $b, ...];` ["arrow functions"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php)

Answer (score 165, accepted):

The recommended way to do this is with an [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
$functions = [
  'function1' => function ($echo) {
        echo $echo;
   }
];
```

If you want to store a function that has already been declared then you can simply refer to it by name as a string:

```
function do_echo($echo) {
    echo $echo;
}

$functions = [
  'function1' => 'do_echo'
];
```

In ancient versions of PHP (<5.3) anonymous functions are not supported and you may need to resort to using  [`create_function`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) (deprecated since PHP 7.2):

```
$functions = array(
  'function1' => create_function('$echo', 'echo $echo;')
);
```

All of these methods are listed in the documentation under the [`callable` pseudo-type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Whichever you choose, the function can either be called directly (PHP ≥5.4) or with [`call_user_func`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)/[`call_user_func_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```
$functions['function1']('Hello world!');

call_user_func($functions['function1'], 'Hello world!');
```

Comment: about call_user_func: Is $var = $functions["function1"], when function1 returns a value, bad practice?

Comment: Hi @Roy. As `$functions["functions1"]` contains a callable assigning it to `$var` will cause `$var` to also contain a callable. You would still need to call it with `$var()` to get the return value.

Comment: Just found a slight bug that the PHP 5.3 method doesn't work if the array is a class member such as: class MyClass { $functions = [
  'function1' => function($echo) {
        echo $echo;
   }
]; }

Comment: @ZackMorris comment should be pointed out in the answer since it isn't an unreasonable idea to do this in a class (it happened at least twice to me before finding his comment)

Comment: @frollo I think you and Zack are encountering a slightly different issue. You can store functions in class members just fine but you can't do so _at compile time_. See this answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28832820/69713

Comment: Well, I tried Zack's code and it didn't work for me so I thought it was the same problem. If it has been fixed I will ask my IT about updating the server, maybe we missed something

Comment: Looks like quotes around do_echo is not necessary in this example 

function do_echo($echo) {
    echo $echo;
}

$functions = array(
  'function1' => 'do_echo'
);
I have used like: do_echo()

Comment: from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php)
**`Warning
This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.`**

Comment: Would you mind updating the answer with PHP 7.4 version (arrow functions) and adding a warning about deprecated `create_function()`?

Answer (score 11):

Since PHP "5.3.0 Anonymous functions become available", example of usage:

***note that this is much faster than using old `create_function`...***

```
//store anonymous function in an array variable e.g. $a["my_func"]
$a = array(
    "my_func" => function($param = "no parameter"){ 
        echo "In my function. Parameter: ".$param;
    }
);

//check if there is some function or method
if( is_callable( $a["my_func"] ) ) $a["my_func"](); 
    else echo "is not callable";
// OUTPUTS: "In my function. Parameter: no parameter"

echo "\n<br>"; //new line

if( is_callable( $a["my_func"] ) ) $a["my_func"]("Hi friend!"); 
    else echo "is not callable";
// OUTPUTS: "In my function. Parameter: Hi friend!"

echo "\n<br>"; //new line

if( is_callable( $a["somethingElse"] ) ) $a["somethingElse"]("Something else!"); 
    else echo "is not callable";
// OUTPUTS: "is not callable",(there is no function/method stored in $a["somethingElse"])
```

Since PHP 7.4 there are also "Arrow functions"

> Arrow functions provide a shorthand syntax for defining functions with implicit by-value scope binding.

It's very similar to the "classic" anonymous function, however it supports only 1 expression and not a block of commands - often used for quick filtering and comparing:

E.g. to get a list of IDs from a book object list:

```
$extractIds = fn (object $o) => $o->getId();
$bookIds = array_map($extractIds, $books);
```

**A great use with spaceship (`<=>`) operator:**

```
$someArray = [2,3,1];
$sort = [
    SORT_ASC => fn($a, $b) => $a <=> $b,
    SORT_DESC => fn($a, $b) => $b <=> $a,
];
usort($someArray, $sort[SORT_ASC]); // someArray will contain: 1, 2, 3
usort($someArray, $sort[SORT_DESC]); // someArray will contain:  3, 2, 1
```

*Constants note: So far (PHP8.2, 2023) PHP doesn't allow storing anonymous functions (nor arrow versions) as constants.*

**REFERENCES:**

- Anonymous function:
  https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php
- Arrow function:
  https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php
- Arrow function (release notes):
  https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.arrow-functions
- Test for callable: https://www.php.net/is_callable

Answer (score 9):

> **Warning** `create_function()` has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

To follow up on Alex Barrett's post,  create_function()  returns a value that you can actually use to call the function, thusly:

```
$function = create_function('$echo', 'echo $echo;' );
$function('hello world');
```

Answer (score 2):

Not mentioned yet: arrow functions (7.4+) are useful for keeping syntax terse and capturing read-only properties from the enclosing scope.

```php
<?php

$ops = [
    'add' => fn($x, $y) => $x + $y,
    'sub' => fn($x, $y) => $x - $y,
    'mul' => fn($x, $y) => $x * $y,
    'div' => fn($x, $y) => $x / $y,
];

// test it
var_dump($ops['add'](6, 2)); // => 8
var_dump($ops['sub'](6, 2)); // => 4
var_dump($ops['mul'](6, 2)); // => 12
var_dump($ops['div'](6, 2)); // => 3

foreach ($ops as $name => $fn) {
    echo "$name => " . $fn(6, 2) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: I would say this example is not very informative, as for some reason it hides the actual arrow function behind regular functions. Only a person already familiar with arrow functions will recognize it. Why not to rewrite the entire example to arrow functions, making it much cleaner easier to grasp?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks for the feedback. I tried updating, hopefully it's clearer even though I'm not showing binding any longer.

Answer (score 1):

Because I could...

Expanding on Alex Barrett's post.

I will be working on further refining this idea, maybe even to something like an external static class, possibly using the '...' token to allow variable length arguments.

In the following example I have used the keyword 'array' for clarity however square brackets would also be fine. The layout shown which employs an init function is intended to demonstrate organization for more complex code.

```
<?php
// works as per php 7.0.33

class pet {
    private $constructors;

    function __construct() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        $index = func_num_args()-1;
        $this->init();

        // Alex Barrett's suggested solution
        // call_user_func($this->constructors[$index], $args);  

        // RibaldEddie's way works also
        $this->constructors[$index]($args); 
    }

    function init() {
        $this->constructors = array(
            function($args) { $this->__construct1($args[0]); },
            function($args) { $this->__construct2($args[0], $args[1]); }
        );
    }

    function __construct1($animal) {
        echo 'Here is your new ' . $animal . '<br />';
    }

    function __construct2($firstName, $lastName) {
        echo 'Name-<br />';
        echo 'First: ' . $firstName . '<br />';
        echo 'Last: ' . $lastName;
    }
}

$t = new pet('Cat');
echo '<br />';
$d = new pet('Oscar', 'Wilding');
?>
```

Ok, refined down to one line now as...

```
function __construct() {
    $this->{'__construct' . (func_num_args()-1)}(...func_get_args());
}
```

Can be used to overload any function, not just constructors.

Answer (score 0):

By using closure we can store a function in a array. Basically a closure is a function that can be created without a specified name - an anonymous function.

```
$a = 'function';
$array=array(
    "a"=> call_user_func(function() use ($a) {
        return $a;
    })
);
var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is what worked for me

```
function debugPrint($value = 'll'){

    echo $value; 
}

$login = '';


$whoisit = array( "wifi" => 'a', "login" => 'debugPrint', "admin" => 'c' );
 
foreach ($whoisit as $key => $value) {
     
    if(isset($$key)) {  
     // in this case login exists as a variable and I am using the value of login to store the function I want to call 
        $value(); } 
}
```