# When using a PHP function that requires a callback, how do we pass a custom parameter to the callback?

Tags: php, callback, parameters

For example,

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

```
<?php
// this text was used in 2002
// we want to get this up to date for 2003
$text = "April fools day is 04/01/2002\n";
$text.= "Last christmas was 12/24/2001\n";
// the callback function
function next_year($matches)
{
// as usual: $matches[0] is the complete match
// $matches[1] the match for the first subpattern
// enclosed in '(...)' and so on
return $matches[1].($matches[2]+1);
}
echo preg_replace_callback(
"|(\d{2}/\d{2}/)(\d{4})|",
"next_year",
$text);

?>
```

If we want to pass a custom parameter to the next_year callback function, how can we do that without using create_function()?

Many thanks to you all.

Comment: depends on your version of php. Are you using php 5.3? If not, then create_function is the way to go.

Comment: Can't you just set a variable and have the callback reference it?

Comment: @Jonathan Fingland: I am using PHP5.2, I am worried create_function() will slow down the match and replace process a lot because if it's used, everytime preg_replace_callback is called, the callback function will always need to be created by create_function in runtime again.

Comment: @lan Kemp: you mean using a global variable?

Comment: `create_function` is a mess - Stay clear of it. Use an object instance to enclose state, for < 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took S. Gehrigs idea and went a bit further with it, why not not put all the replacement functionality inside the class?

```
<?php
class Replacer {

    private $additional = 'X';

    private function next_year($matches)
    {
        // as usual: $matches[0] is the complete match
        // $matches[1] the match for the first subpattern
        // enclosed in '(...)' and so on
        return $this->additional . $matches[1].($matches[2]+1);
    }

    public function replace_years($text)
    {
        return preg_replace_callback( "|(\d{2}/\d{2}/)(\d{4})|", array($this, 'next_year'), $text);
    }
}


$text = "April fools day is 04/01/2002\n";
$text.= "Last christmas was 12/24/2001\n";

$Replacer = new Replacer();
echo $Replacer->replace_years($text);
```

And the result is:

```
[~]> php test.php
April fools day is X04/01/2003
Last christmas was X12/24/2002
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's the easiest solution, but I'd go for a object-method callback, where the object carries the required parameters in its state:

```
class Callback
{
    public $parameter;

    public function handle($matches)
    {
        return $matches[1] . ($matches[2] + $this->parameter);
    }
}

$instance = new Callback();
$instance->parameter = 99;
echo preg_replace_callback("|(\d{2}/\d{2}/)(\d{4})|", array($instance, 'handle'), $text);
```

Second option would be to resort to global variables:

```
$parameter = 99;

function next_year($matches)
{
    global $parameter;
    return $matches[1] . ($matches[2] + $parameter);
}
echo preg_replace_callback("|(\d{2}/\d{2}/)(\d{4})|", "next_year", $text);
```

Comment: using a global variable is easier, but if I put that in a class as a static variable, is this thread safe?

Comment: PHP doesn't have threads. Each PHP script runs in its own process. I would use the object instance method as in Gehrigs first example.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will go for your object instance method.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`callback` pseudo-type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback), you can pass any variant of that to `preg_replace_callback`.

Here is an answer I gave yesterday, giving an overview of the type: [Can you store a function in a PHP array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499862/can-you-store-a-function-in-a-php-array/1499867#1499867)

Answer (score 0):

The [*callback* pseudo-type](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) is just a string with the name of a function. So you can either declare the function like any other function and use that name just like you did. Or you use the `create_function` to declare a function on execution. `create_function` will then return the name of the newly created function `lambda_`*`x`*. (Since PHP 5.3 you can also use the [anonymouse function syntax](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).)

But since *callback* is just the name of a function, you could use a function to create that function on the fly and return the name of that newley created function like this:

```
function shift_years($years) {
    return create_function('$matches', 'return $matches[1].($matches[2]+'.((int)$years).');');
}
$func = shift_years(123);
echo preg_replace_callback("|(\d{2}/\d{2}/)(\d{4})|", $func, $text);
```

Now `shift_years` creates your custom *callback* function as specified.

Comment: is create_function very slow that we should try to avoid it?

Comment: @bobo: Sorry, I have no data on that. But I think if you create that function just once and then use the anonymous function’s name to reference it, there will be no considerable performance loss.

Comment: i see, your curried function is also a nice one.