# add function to an array in php

Tags: php

I'm having trouble declaring an array in conjunction to a function.  Here is my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
private function array_list(){
    return array('1'=>'one', '2'=>'two');
}

private $arrays= array(
    'a'=>array('type'=>'1', 'list'=>$this->array_list())
);
```

Getting  unexpected T_VARIABLE error when I run this code.

Comment: please provide the whole class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499862/can-you-store-a-function-in-a-php-array

Comment: You can't use variables when defining properties on a class. Everything provided in a property definition needs to be (constant as opposed to dynamic).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare arrays like this as property:

```
private $arrays= array(
    'a'=>array('type'=>'1', 'list'=>$this->array_list())
);
```

You cannot use an array returned from a class method in the property definition.
You should populate it inside a constructor for example. Like this:

```
private $arrays = array();

public function __construct() {
    $this->arrays = array(
        'a'=>array('type'=>'1', 'list'=>$this->array_list())
    ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it in a method, for example, the constructor:

```
class Foo {
    function __construct () {
        $this->arrays['list'] = $this->array_list ();
    }
}
```