# PHP: closure to set variable

Tags: php, closures

In PHP closures are quite useful. But can I use closures to set array elements?

```
$configs = [
    "y" => "1",
    "x" => function() { return "xxx"; },
];
echo $configs["y"];
echo $configs["x"];  // error
```

gives

```
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Closure could not
be converted to string on line 6 (last line)
```

Is there a chance to cast the closure or anything the like that the closure works for array initialization?

Working with PHP 7.1.4 on MacOSX

Comment: maybe this answer help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/9443941/1779650

Comment: Not really. I want to execute the closure immediately to get the array element initialized. I don't need the closure function later on in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an *IIFE* (Immediately Invoked Function Expression):

```
$configs = [
  'y' => '1',
  'x' => (function () { return 'xxx'; })()
];

echo $configs['x'];
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/O0fEm**

Comment: Can we invoke the closure during definition in line 3? How?

Comment: @WeSee Yes. See my edit for an alternative version using an IIFE (PHP 7 only).

Answer (score 0):

I would define the function apart:

```
function test(){   
    echo "Hello";
}
```

And then assign the result to a variable:

```
$a = test();
echo $a; //Returns "Hello"
```

Comment: In my case that doesn't work. I have a config-Array where array variables are being set...

Comment: Then edit your post and show us what do you have so we can help you with more precision ^^ @WeSee