# Function name in Array

Tags: php, arrays, class, function

I have a problem in calling a function that the name is being stored in an array.

```
class tempClass {
   function someFunction() {
      $tempArray = array('functionName' => 'tempFunction');
      $tempArray['functionName']();
   }

   function tempFunction() {
      echo "inside function";
   }
}
```

It gives me an error:

```
"Fatal error: Call to undefined function tempFunction() in /..... line..".
```

Line number is the line where the function is being called, `$tempArray['functionName']();`

But if called the `method_exists()`, it shows that the method is exists. It is very confusing. Can anyone please help me out? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you store a function in a PHP array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499862/can-you-store-a-function-in-a-php-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [call_user_func()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) , like this:

```
call_user_func($tempArray['functionName']);
```

**UPDATE:**
As you want to call a method of a class from inside that class, use the following instead:

```
call_user_func(array($this, $tempArray['functionName']));
```

See working [**demo**](http://codepad.org/Qm202eOv)

Comment: I got this error "Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'tempFunction' not found or invalid function name in...."

Comment: Same problem as with your original attempt: you are missing the scope.

Comment: yes you are right, How stupid of me. I used $this->$tempArray['functionName'](); and it worked. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: @AbhishekSalian I've updated my answer with a corrected version for your case (calling a method of the class from within the class), check it out.

Comment: @arkascha Yes I didn't notice it first time, check out my update for the fixed version.

Comment: @arkascha Because your answer is not working, as OP told you, you'd notice if you actually run it, see the error here http://codepad.org/CIT7IDhT

Comment: @Nelson: you are right, sorry for the confusion. I update my answer accordingly, yours is the better answer!

Answer (score 2):

Well you ask if the method exists inside the class or object, but you call it without that scope. That won't work...

Try this instead:

```
call_user_method($tempArray['functionName'],$this);
```

Just saw that `call_user_method()` is depreciated. Use `call_user_func()` as answered by Nelson instead.

Comment: it didnt work with the above cmd but i just added the scope to the calling function. thanks.

Comment: This answer does not work, the error can be seen here http://codepad.org/CIT7IDhT

Comment: @Nelson: that is true, sorry for that. I corrected the answer, but Nelsons answer is better: just saw that `call_user_mothod` is depreciated! Sorry for the confusion.