# Can I make an array of functions?

Tags: php, arrays, function, hook

Can I make an array of functions and execute the functions with a foreach loop?

Like:

```
// This is the beginning of the php file
global $actions = array();

// This is the function where functions need to be added.
function HeadFunction(){
 foreach($actions as $action) 
 $action;
}
```

This is the function to add the action

```
function add_action($action){
global $actions;
$actions[] = $action;
}
```

This is a example function:

```
function check_Url(){
 if(isset($_GET['gettest'])){
    echo '<script>alert(\'This is a test\');</script>';
 }
}
```

and then add the function with: add_action(check_Url());

Comment: sounds possible but a bad idea

Comment: It's possible `$action` should be `$action()` to call.

Comment: It is to create a hook, in for example the header of a webpage. So you can add functions with add_action() to the header.

Comment: You are my hero Sheikh Heera! Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you store a function in a PHP array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499862/can-you-store-a-function-in-a-php-array)

Answer (score 0):

Use `call_user_func`.

```
global $actions = array();

function add_action($action){
global $actions;
$actions[] = $action;
}

add_action('check_Url');
add_action('function2');

foreach ($actions AS $action) {
    call_user_func($action);
}
```

Comment: Thank you David Xu! Sheikh Heera pointed out that $action should be $action(), and it worked. What do you think is better way? Adding strings to $actions[] to call $action() vs adding functions to $actions[] and call call_user_func($action)?