# Function literal in PHP class

Tags: php, function, oop, literals

Take a look at this code, please:

```
$array = array(
    'action' => function () { echo "this works"; }
);

class Test {
    public $array = array(
        "action" => function () { echo "this doesn't"; }
    );
}
```

The first function literal parses fine, but the second - the one inside the class - triggers a syntax error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION)...

Can somebody explain this to me? Is this a bug?

EDIT: This is the latest PHP: 5.6.6

Comment: Which PHP version is this, exactly?

Comment: Property declarations can only be constants/literals. Anonymous functions are expressions.

Comment: Use a constructor and it will work, you cannot assign class variables with none-literals on instantiation. They need to be set in the constructor.

Comment: My mistake, it seems. Apparently function literals aren't constant.

Comment: Just a sidenote, in PHP7 you'll get another warning: Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations. And it's occuring on the next line in comparisson to your current error.

Comment: You want know how to resolve this problem, or You want to know, this is bug?

Comment: I only wanted to know if this is intended behaviour, because this doesn't make any sense to me. But, yeah, it's intended, so I'll make do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832708/function-literal-in-php-class/28835028#28835028

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the class it's a property !

Rule from properties :

> Declaration may include an initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a **constant value**--that is, it must be able to
>   be **evaluated** at **compile time** and must **not depend on run-time**
>   information in order to be evaluated.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: Yeah. Seems I should have read the docs more thoroughly :( Still... this is annoying. But thanks!

Comment: This is a correct answer, but their wording is ambiguous: how exactly `function () { echo "this doesn't"; }` "depends on run-time information"?

Comment: @georg That's another question entirely.

Answer (score 4):

I dont have chance to test Your code on PHP 5.6.6, but I think this code resolve Your problem.

```
class Test{

    public $array;

    function __construct(){

            $this -> array = array(

                'action'    =>  function (){

                    echo 'It works too';
                }
            );
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test -> array['action']();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, let me know if this works for you

```
<?php
$array = array('action' => function () { echo "this works"; });
class Test {
    public $arr;
    function __construct() {
        $this->arr = array("action" => function () { echo "this works too"; });
    }
    function getArr(){
        var_dump($this->arr);
    }
}

var_dump($array);
$obj = new Test();
$obj->getArr();
```

Comment: Thanks! That would work, but it doesn't exactly make my code easier to read. I'll probably drop the data into the global namespace. If PHP's OOP wants to be capricious, so can I.